# Combining Multiple page CSS into a single file

Tags: html, css

What if i combine all the CSS of the complete site into a single file.
would it be cached by the browser or be reloaded every single time a new page is opened.
the single css file contains different values for different pages.
should i divide the css for different pages or keep it in a single file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the files are probably better of combined but will only be cached if the correct headers are set. I suggest downloading YSlow (or Page Speed) which is a plugin for firebug which analyses your page and shows how it is slow and gives advice on how to improve it.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Also look at css minification tools like those in the YUI toolkit to compress the css code as well as combining the files.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1):

Combining CSS files into one will give you better performance. You can compare this in FireBug( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843 ) in FireFox.

If you use asp.net have a look at the ScriptReferenceProfiler, it shows the list of downloaded resources, these can be combined to improve performance: see blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/06/26/asp-net-ajax-scriptreferenceprofiler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, combining your CSS into a single file is a good practice for production servers. The single file reduces the number of http requests required and, in both cases (single or mutiple files) caching will be used.

The benefit of fewer http requests is greatest for first time visitors.

Also, you reduce the number of requests required on subsequent pages as the file will have been cached. (think of it as pre-loading the css if the portions unused on the current page seems wasteful to you)

Comment: Caching will not necessarily happen. It depends on the cachability if caching will actually take place.

Comment: @Gumbo, as I'm sure you know, it depends on a number of factors including headers sent by the server (e.g. expiration date) and settings on the client machine (some folks browse cache-less).

Answer (score 0):

Most sane browsers will cache CSS files, so compacting them down into a single file can help a little when it comes to request times. However, maintainability is also an issue - if you have difficulty maintaining the CSS code when it's all in a single file, you may still want to stick with separate files.

In the end it's up to you, whatever feels best.

Comment: Or - use a mechanism which merges them. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is is good to have one file. Please see for the file size also that might affect the page load time. All browser catch the css files. Next time it will not load new one.

Please use the [yahoo info](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) for that.